# Execute an Update on an Unmapped Table

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I need for some reasons make a delete on a unmapped many-to-many table (automatically generated table). I haven't found out how to execute such a update with in grails or hibernate.

What I would like to have is something like:

```
session.executeUpdate("delete from person_titles where person_id=?", [personId])
```

but of course there is not `executeUpdate` method on a hibernate session instance. And I can't do a `session.delete(...)`, since this table is not mapped.

I hope, there is an easy way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `createSQLQuery` method:

```
Query deleteQuery = session.createSQLQuery("delete from person_titles where person_id=?");
deleteQuery.setInteger(0, personId);
int deleted = deleteQuery.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to achieve that myself:

```
def sql = new groovy.sql.Sql (dataSource)
def deleteCommand = "delete from person_titles where person_id = ${personId}"
def result = sql.execute(deleteCommand)
```